# Is NodeJS required for a build Electron App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have created my own app using electron and now built it using electron-packager to an .app file.

Of course on my Mac — with NodeJS installed — it works. Now I wonder if it would work if I sent my app to a friend who doesn't have NodeJS installed.
So my question is: **Is NodeJS required to run a packaged electron app?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you've packaged your app correctly you will be able to send it to your friend (you probably need to zip / dmg the app because it contains symlinks). Your friend does not need to install electron nor node beforehand -- it should all be packaged already (including all your node modules).

Comment: Thank you. I already have it as a dmg so it should work, right?

Comment: Yes. Obviously there are things that can go wrong (you need to include all required node module compiled for the right platform etc.), but the idea is that you can distribute your app without requiring users to install Node or Electron first. For example, see how apps like Atom are distributed.

Comment: Can I ask here? I want to create Windows Store app using electron. Does user need to install nodejs in their PC to be able to run my app after installing it from Windows Store?